# How to set PivotTable Field Number Format Cell with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

I'd like to set *number format cell* of pivot table Value field *Sum of Balance* as `# ##0`.

Pivot table created with code based on [Official POI Sample CreatePivotTable](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/CreatePivotTable.java)

Code below do `create` and `get` `CTPivotField pivotField`. But how to set its number format?

```java
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 2);
CTPivotField pivotField = pivotTable
    .getCTPivotTableDefinition()
    .getPivotFields()
    .getPivotFieldArray(2);
```

In MS Excel this is doing by next steps (see screenshot):

1. right click on *Sum of Balance* pivot table Value
2. select *Field Settings*
3. click *Number...*
4. set *Format Cells*

Help please with decide, advice or any idea.

[image: Setting number format cell of pivot table with Microsoft Excel]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Format of pivot table fields is setting by `CTDataField.setNumFmtId(long numFmtId)` **for values** and `CTPivotField.setNumFmtId(long numFmtId)` **for columns & rows**.

`numFmtId` is id number of format code. Available format codes are represented in Format cells list - Custom category:
[image]
Predefined format codes, thanks to [Ji Zhou - MSFT](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e27aaf16-b900-4654-8210-83c5774a179c/xlsx-numfmtid-predefined-id-14-doesnt-match?forum=oxmlsdk), is here:

```
1 0    
2 0.00    
3 #,##0    
4 #,##0.00    
5 $#,##0_);($#,##0)    
6 $#,##0_);[Red]($#,##0)    
7 $#,##0.00_);($#,##0.00)    
8 $#,##0.00_);[Red]($#,##0.00)    
9 0%    
10 0.00%    
11 0.00E+00    
12 # ?/?    
13 # ??/??    
14 m/d/yyyy    
15 d-mmm-yy    
16 d-mmm    
17 mmm-yy    
18 h:mm AM/PM    
19 h:mm:ss AM/PM    
20 h:mm    
21 h:mm:ss    
22 m/d/yyyy h:mm    
37 #,##0_);(#,##0)    
38 #,##0_);[Red](#,##0)    
39 #,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)    
40 #,##0.00_);[Red](#,##0.00)    
45 mm:ss    
46 [h]:mm:ss    
47 mm:ss.0    
48 ##0.0E+0    
49 @
```

Full list of predefined format codes in [MSDN NumberingFormat Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.numberingformat%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Here is an example of applying format pivot table fields:

```java
package ru.inkontext.poi;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataConsolidateFunction;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPivotTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataFields;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class CreatePivotTableSimple {

    private static void setFormatPivotField(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable,
                                                long fieldIndex,
                                                Integer numFmtId) {
        Optional.ofNullable(pivotTable
                .getCTPivotTableDefinition()
                .getPivotFields())
                .map(pivotFields -> pivotFields
                        .getPivotFieldArray((int) fieldIndex))
                .ifPresent(pivotField -> pivotField
                        .setNumFmtId(numFmtId));
    }

    private static void setFormatDataField(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable,
                                               long fieldIndex,
                                               long numFmtId) {
        Optional.ofNullable(pivotTable
                .getCTPivotTableDefinition()
                .getDataFields())
                .map(CTDataFields::getDataFieldList)
                .map(List::stream)
                .ifPresent(stream -> stream
                        .filter(dataField -> dataField.getFld() == fieldIndex)
                        .findFirst()
                        .ifPresent(dataField -> dataField.setNumFmtId(numFmtId)));
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

        //Create some data to build the pivot table on
        setCellData(sheet);

        XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(
                new AreaReference("A1:C6", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007),
                new CellReference("E3"));

        pivotTable.addRowLabel(1); // set second column as 1-th level of rows
        setFormatPivotField(pivotTable, 1, 9); //set format of row field numFmtId=9 0%
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(0); // set first column as 2-th level of rows
        pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 2); // Sum up the second column
        setFormatDataField(pivotTable, 2, 3); //set format of value field numFmtId=3 # ##0

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("stackoverflow-pivottable.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        wb.close();
    }

    private static void setCellData(XSSFSheet sheet) {

        String[] names = {"Jane", "Tarzan", "Terk", "Kate", "Dmitry"};
        Double[] percents = {0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.25, 0.5};
        Integer[] balances = {107634, 554234, 10234, 22350, 15234};

        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Name");
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Percents");
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue("Balance");

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            row = sheet.createRow(i + 1);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(names[i]);
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(percents[i]);
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(balances[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/stolbovd/PoiSamples

Comment: There is no number format having single decimal i.e 0.0. How to show numbers with single decimal then ?