# [APACHE-POI]: Apply style to pivot-table cells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot, pivot-table

I'm trying to apply some cell style to a code-generated excel pivot-table with Apache-poi.

I can't find any documentation/example about this and I'm afraid there is no way to set cell style to a pivot-table.

I've tried to cycle over rows, but Apache-poi pivot-table don't have any row!

This is the actual code that produces the pivot table:

```
    XSSFSheet dataSheet = ((XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheet(sheetName));

    int firstRow = dataSheet.getFirstRowNum();
    int lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRowNum();
    int firstCol = dataSheet.getRow(0).getFirstCellNum();
    int lastCol = dataSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

    CellReference topLeft = new CellReference(sheetName, firstRow, firstCol, false, false);
    CellReference botRight = new CellReference(sheetName, lastRow, lastCol - 1, false, false);

    AreaReference dataSheetAreaReference = new AreaReference(topLeft, botRight, null);

    List<Map<String, Object>> pivotWidgetFields = castedParams.getFields();
    List<Map<String, Object>> pivotRowFields = pivotWidgetFields.stream().filter(field -> field.get("area").equals("row")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Map<String, Object>> pivotColumnFields = pivotWidgetFields.stream().filter(field -> field.get("area").equals("column")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Map<String, Object>> pivotValueFields = pivotWidgetFields.stream().filter(field -> field.get("area").equals("data")).collect(Collectors.toList());

    XSSFSheet pivotSheet = ((XSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet("Pivot sheet"));
    XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(dataSheetAreaReference, new CellReference("A1"));
 // row and column fields setup here [...]
```

This is the result:
[image: result pivot-table]

Can I style a pivot cell based on cell value?
Something like:

```
if (cell.getValue().equals("Ricavi Vendita CEE ~ (353)")) {
    cell.setCellStyle("someStyle");
}
```

And then see a result like this:
[image: styled pivot]

Thanks in advance!

[UPDATE]:

Can't change cell style, for example color or background color, with proposed duplicate answer.
That solutions only helps me with number format on pivot field.

```
private static void setFormatPivotField(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable,
                                            long fieldIndex,
                                            Integer numFmtId) {
    Optional.ofNullable(pivotTable
            .getCTPivotTableDefinition()
            .getPivotFields())
            .map(pivotFields -> pivotFields
                    .getPivotFieldArray((int) fieldIndex))
            .ifPresent(pivotField -> pivotField
                    .setNumFmtId(numFmtId));
}
```

That code can't access field styling such color or background.
I need to apply styles to string row fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set PivotTable Field Number Format Cell with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511928/how-to-set-pivottable-field-number-format-cell-with-apache-poi)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer thanks for the tip, but trying to follow that post I still can't apply some style to a pivot-table field programmatically

Comment: Include that as an update in your question. Post the new code you use and explain what fails/doesnt work and if there is any exception etc